# Video.js Unit Level Hls.xhr.beforeRequest Function

Tags: video, video.js, aws-amplify

I am following [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amplify-video/wiki/Play-Assets) VOD Amplify Video Tutorial in order to upload and stream video on demand. Amplify Video automatically restricts the "output" S3 bucket of HLS videos, in which a token must be appended to the each HLS URL that is fired from the Video.js unit in order to access it.

The tutorial recommends using the `videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest` function in order to append this token to every m3u8 request fired, as follows:

```
videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = (options) => {
  options.uri = `${options.uri}${token}`;
  return options;
}
```

though this is a global function, so breaks if there are 2 seperate video units loading seperate videos on the page.

Is there a way to mimic the function of the `beforeRequest` function, but on a unit level rather than a global level.

EDIT:

I have a temporary solution, though it is quite messy and would be open to other solutions. Rather than passing through the token to each individual unit I have a global object `videoTokens` where each token is set as { videoId: token }, then in my beforeRequest function I get the ID from the URL, then pull the token out from that global object (I am using Vue and Vuex):

```
videojs.Vhs.xhr.beforeRequest = (options) => {
  const splitUrl = options.uri.split(".");
  const splitId = splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 2].split("/");
  const id = splitId[splitId.length - 2];
  const token = this.$store.state.videoTokens[id] || "";

  options.uri = `${options.uri}${token}`;
  return options;
}
```

Then in my beforeDestroy on the component I delete that key to avoid storing too many.

As mentioned would be open to other cleaner solutions.